# Пропажа элементов после другой анимации. C#

Tags: wpf, wpf-canvas

У меня есть `Canvas` в котором есть `label`. А также есть `webBrowser1` на котором есть анимации. По вызову кнопки воспроизводится анимация открытия `WebBrowser`, при повторном нажатии воспроизводится анимация закрытия `WebBrowser`. После закрытия появляется `Canvas` с чёрным фоном и пустой. Z у всех равен 1000.

Код анимации:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="BrowserOpen">
            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="200,44,0,0" To="827,44,0,0" DecelerationRatio="0.9" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Key="BrowserClose">
            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="827,44,0,0" To="200,44,0,0" DecelerationRatio="0.9" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
        </Storyboard>
```

Comment: Потому что у вас ужасно бешенные значение Margin. Не в коем случае не расставляйте объекты через конструктор, он годиться исключительно для просмотра результата, не более. Выучите XAML, он очень прост. И я вам уже сказал, что это не WPF, перешли, значит переходите правильно - учите привязки!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а не оверкилл ли выносить в биндинги данные касающиеся сугубо расположения/отображения элементов? Я бы оставил все это в разметке.

Comment: @yolosora Я разве сказал про вынос всего в отдельное место для привязок? Человек перешел с WinForms и работает до сих пор по его правилам, не понимая, что в WPF правила совсем другие, вот к этому я и веду. Тут например у него Margin, который явно сгенерирован студией, в WinForms может и сойдет такое, в WPF нет! Я уверен, что у человека почти нет привязок, обращение идет через измена, разметка генерируется через код, это тоже неуместно в WPF. Посмотрите например предыдущий вопрос, там у него разом выводится все на экран, только друг за другом и нужное выводит на передний план - тоже бред.